# Bash script stopped recognizing substitute file

Tags: bash, scripting

I've got this script

```
#!/bin/bash
name=test.sqlite
idx=1
while [ -e $name.$idx ]; do 
    idx=`expr $idx + 1`; 
done
while [ $idx -gt 1 ]; do 
    nidx=`expr $idx - 1`; mv $name.$nidx $name.$idx; idx=$nidx; 
done
[ ! -e $name ] || mv $name $name.1
sqlite3 test.sqlite < /path/to/db_schema.sh
```

and `db_schema.sh`

```
create table objects(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, crc integer not null);
create index objects_idx on objects(crc);

create table symbols(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, crc integer not null);
create index symbols_idx on symbols(crc);

create table provides(object_id integer not null, symbol_id integer not null);
create index provides_idx_sym on provides(symbol_id);
create index provides_idx_obj on provides(object_id);
create unique index provides_idx_key on provides(object_id, symbol_id);

create table depends(object_id integer not null, symbol_id integer not null);
create index depends_idx_sym on depends(symbol_id);
create index depends_idx_obj on depends(object_id);
create unique index depends_idx_key on depends(object_id,symbol_id);
```

This did work until today. 
What I tried so far

1. hard-coding the path to `db_schema.sh`
2. setting a variable to the file (`$DB_SCHEMA_VAR`)
3. setting the path as variable but hardcoding the file (`$PATH_TO_FILE/db_schema.sh`)
4. changing the folder the file is in and the three above

I also checked if the file is executable (it is), wrote a little line testing if the file is present

```
if [ -f db_schema.sh ] ; then ....
```

before the database gets created. The test shows `db_schema.sh` is there, but as soon as `db_schema.sh`  gets called, it suddenly is no longer present.

And here the log output as asked for by Barefoot IO

```
+ DB_INIT (this is because i call it as a function and it is not a stand-alone script)
+ cd DB_wdsfasdfg
+ name=test.sqlite
+ idx=1
+ '[' -e test.sqlite.1 ']'
+ '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
+ '[' '!' -e test.sqlite ']'
+ sqlite3 test.sqlite
./files/functions/init_db.sh: line 22: ./files/functions/db_schema.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's the error? There's a few things happening on your script -- narrow it down to the problem area.

Comment: It would be helpful if you traced the script and shared the log: `bash -x scriptfile 2> trace.log`.

Comment: gonna add this, it may take a moment

Answer (score 1):

I assume that init_db.sh and db_schema.sh are in the same directory.

The combination of `cd` and a file name that's relative to the current working directory, `./files/functions/db_schema.sh`, suggests that db_schema.sh cannot be found because the current working directory is no longer what it was at the time that `./files/functions/init_db.sh` was invoked.

If the script was in the correct directory before `cd DB_wdsfasdfg`, then perhaps it will suffice to return to that directory, using `cd -`, before invoking `sqlite3`.

Alternatively, you can specify an absolute pathname -- a pathname beginning with a `/` -- which is independent of the current directory.